# mysql - how to create a id column for a column

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, wampserver, mysql-connector

i want to create a table that have 3 column :

1. visit_times : have a unique id for every specific visitor
2. visitor_ID
3. Date

i tryed to create the table as showing this code

> CREATE TABLE `test`.`table` ( `visit_times` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `visitor_ID` INT NOT NULL , `Date` VARCHAR NOT NULL , UNIQUE `Unique column` (`visit_times`, `visitor_ID`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

but when i store this data into the table

```
INSERT INTO `tab`(`visitor_ID`, `date`) VALUES ("1", "15/05/2021");
INSERT INTO `tab`(`visitor_ID`, `date`) VALUES ("1", "20/07/2021");
INSERT INTO `tab`(`visitor_ID`, `date`) VALUES ("2", "02/09/2021");
INSERT INTO `tab`(`visitor_ID`, `date`) VALUES ("3", "24/08/2021");
```

the result it will be like this

| visit_times | visitor_ID | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15/05/2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 20/07/2021 |
| 3 | 2 | 02/09/2021 |
| 4 | 3 | 24/08/2021 |

and what i actually want as result

| visit_times | visitor_ID | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15/05/2021 |
| 2 | 1 | 20/07/2021 |
| 1 | 2 | 02/09/2021 |
| 1 | 3 | 24/08/2021 |

Server version: 8.0.21 - MySQL Community Server - GPL

I use Wampserver version 3.2.3 - 64bit

Apache Version : 2.4.46

---

Thanks for helping

Comment: FYI "visiter" is spelt "visitor" in English.

Comment: The `visit_times` column is defined as AUTO_INCREMENT so you have told MySQL to add one to the previous `visit_times` rows `visit_times` and use that. You now have NO CONTROL over that column, so either its defined incorrectly or your logic is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by ID_of_visiter order by timecol) as num_of_visit,
       t.*
from t;
```

Comment: but i want it as a column to use it in python and show data in table in tkinter ????